# How to use CASE in my Scenario in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, case

I have to calculate total quantity with certain cases.

`#customerSales` table:

```
ItemLookupCode  TotalQuantity  
-----------------------------
111A000         20           
111B001         320          
111D000         5            
111D001         5            
111D002         1            
111D003         1
```

`#temp_ItemRelations` table

```
ID  ItemLookupCode  ChildItemLookupCode1   Child1Piece    ChildItemLookupCode2  Child2Piece   ChildItemLookupCode    Child3Piece
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
352 111A000         111A001                5                       111A002         3                   NULL             NULL    
365 111B000         111B001                4                       NULL          NULL                  NULL             NULL    
377 111C000         111C001                10                      111C002         5                  111C003            1  
412 111D000         111D001                12                      111D002         8                  111D003            4      
601 111E000         111E001                16                      111E002         6                  111E003            1
```

You can see **111D000** of `ItemLookupCode` in `#temp_ItemRelations`, all children are sold including parent.

So output should be like below

```
 ItemLookupCode     TotalQuantity    //parent    + child1 + child2 + child3
 111D000                77           //  5       + (5*12) + (1*8)  + (1*4)
 111A000                20           //  20      + no child
 111B000               1280          // noparent + (4*320)+ nochild2 & 3
```

I tried the following query. But I don't how to sum those values. I know the following query is wrong. But I tried.

```
SELECT
    ir.ItemLookupCode,
    (CASE 
        WHEN cs.ItemLookupCode = ir.ItemLookupCode 
           THEN cs.TotalQuantity
        WHEN cs.itemlookupcode = ir1.childitemlookupcode1 
           THEN (cs.TotalQuantity * ir.Child1Piece)
        WHEN cs.itemlookupcode = ir2.childitemlookupcode2 
           THEN (cs.TotalQuantity * ir.Child2Piece)
        WHEN cs.itemlookupcode = ir3.childitemlookupcode 
           THEN (cs.TotalQuantity * ir.Child3Piece)
        ELSE 0 
     END) AS TotalQuantity
FROM
    #temp_ItemRelations ir
LEFT JOIN
    #customerSales cs ON cs.itemlookupcode = ir.itemlookupcode 
LEFT JOIN
    #temp_ItemRelations ir1 ON cs.itemlookupcode = ir1.childitemlookupcode1
LEFT JOIN
    #temp_ItemRelations ir2 ON cs.itemlookupcode = ir2.childitemlookupcode2
LEFT JOIN
    #temp_ItemRelations ir3 ON cs.itemlookupcode = ir3.childitemlookupcode
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a bad data structure.  Your item relations should have one row per child relationship, not multiple columns with numbers to distinguish them.

I wouldn't use `case` for this calculation at all, just `coalesce()`.  More importantly, you seem to have the joins to the wrong tables:

```
select ir.ItemLookupCode,
       (coalesce(cs.TotalQuantity, 0) +
        coalesce(cs1.TotalQuantity * ir.Child1Piece, 0) +
        coalesce(cs2.TotalQuantity * ir.Child2Piece, 0) +
        coalesce(cs3.TotalQuantity * ir.Child3Piece, 0)
       ) as TotalQuantity
from #temp_ItemRelations ir left join
      #customerSales cs
      on cs.itemlookupcode = ir.itemlookupcode left join
      #customerSales cs1
      on cs1.itemlookupcode = ir.childitemlookupcode1 left join
      #customerSales cs2
      on cs2.itemlookupcode = ir.childitemlookupcode2 left join
      #customerSales cs3
      on cs3.itemlookupcode = ir.childitemlookupcode3;
```

Comment: can you tell me what is that `coalesce` and why you have added `zero on every coalesce`?

Comment: `coalesce` returns the first non-null argument from the list of arguments given to it. In the code above, `coalesce(cs.TotalQuantity, 0)` equals `cs.TotalQuantity` if it's not null, and 0 otherwise. Since adding 0 to something doesn't change the sum, it acts like a convenient `if` or `case`.

Comment: @mohamedfaiz . . . If the value is `NULL`, then it is treated as `0`.  That prevents the expression from returning `NULL` because one of the operands is `NULL`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff can we do grouping further from **#customerSales** table?

Comment: @mohamedfaiz . . . If you have another question, then ask as a new *question*, along with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

**CASE WHEN condition1 THEN expression1
     WHEN condition2 THEN expression2
...**

This will mean that when condition1 is TRUE, the result will be expression1.
There will only be a check for condition2 when condition1 is FALSE.